# Dynamic generated form with checkbox in Vue

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I have dynamic generated form in Vue. Every loop have v-model. Everything work fine. But when I use checkboxes v-model work for all loops not on one like in input type text. Can You help me solved this problem? Below Vue code:

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-row mb-2" v-for="input, index in journal" :key="index">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <label for="date">Data</label>
      <Datepicker v-model="input.date" input-class="form-control" :input-attr="{id: 'date', name: 'date'}" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="timeStart">Od</label>
      <Datepicker type="time" v-model="input.timeStart" format="HH:mm" input-class="form-control" :input-attr="{id: 'timeStart', name: 'timeStart'}" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="timeEnd">Do</label>
      <Datepicker type="time" v-model="input.timeEnd" format="HH:mm" input-class="form-control" :input-attr="{id: 'timeEnd', name: 'timeEnd'}" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="players">Lista obecności</label>
      <div class="form-check" v-for="item in input.players">
        <input v-model="item.checked" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" :id="'id-'+item.id+'set'+index">
        <label class="form-check-label" :for="'id-'+item.id+'set'+index">{{ item.fullName }}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <label for="description">Opis</label>
      <textarea v-model="input.description" class="form-control" rows="7" id="description" placeholder="Opis"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto" @click="addInput" v-show="index == journal.length-1 && journal.length < 16">
      <ButtonVue style="margin-top: 30px;" title="Dodaj" type="button" cancelWidth="true" color="btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></ButtonVue>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto align-self-start" @click="removeInput(index)" v-show="index || ( !index && journal.length > 1)">
      <ButtonVue style="margin-top: 30px;" title="Usuń" type="button" cancelWidth="true" color="btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></ButtonVue>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
 
data() {
  return {
    contact: [],
    journal: [{
      date: "",
      timeStart: "",
      timeEnd: "",
      players: "",
      description: ""
    }],
    contacts: [],
  }
},
```

Methods:

Method for creating dynamic form

```
addInput() {
  this.journal.push({
    date: "",
    timeStart: "",
    timeEnd: "",
    players: this.contact,
     description: ""
  });
},
```

And here is the method which gets players from contacts

```
getContacts() {
  this.pageLoader = true;
  this.$http.get('/pkpar/get-contacts')
    .then(({
      data
     }) => {
     this.contacts = data.contacts;
     for(let i=0; i<this.contacts.length; i++)
     {   
     this.contact.push({'id': this.contacts[i]['id'], 'fullName' : 
     this.contacts[i]['fullName'], 'checked': true});
     }    
     this.journal[0].players = this.contact;
     this.pageLoader = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Comment: I doubt anyone can help you if you do not provide the example for the content of `players` field used to generate checkboxes...

Comment: I added required methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addInput` method creates and pushes new object into `journal` array, but each object created this way has a `players` property which **references same array** (`this.contact`)

[The Difference Between Values and References in JavaScript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/)

Easiest (but not most optimal) way to handle this is to create a copy of the array and objects inside for each new `journal`:

```js
addInput() {
  this.journal.push({
    date: "",
    timeStart: "",
    timeEnd: "",
    players: this.contact.map((player) => ({ ...player })),
    description: ""
  });
},
```